# I want to track the user that is comming from a mobile messenger and visit my website

Tags: php, mobile, tracking, messenger

I am sharing website in the software such as Line, Whatsapp, Viber, ... and I want to when a person click on the link an visit website understand that where it came from. I don't want to use address like this:example.com/index.php?source=viber. I want to just share example.com and understand that where it come from.

Now I share website like this:

```
example.com/index.php?source=viber
```

Or

```
example.com/index.php?source=whatsapp
```

when a person click on `example.com/index.php?source=viber` and visit my website I understand that this user has come to website from viber but I want to just share `example.com` without `index.php?source=viber` and understand that user has come to website from viber.
Can I do it with HTTP headers in PHP?
I use HTTP_REFERER but it is not useful in this case.

Comment: https://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: Hi @user1672694 . My location is Islamic Republic of Iran and the google analytics is not available for my country because my country is boycott. Website speed down is the other reason that i don't want to use this service.